# Bijection between tensors and permutations (in linear $O(n)$ time)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computational-complexity, tensors

The number of permutations of the set $S=\{1, \dots, n\}$
is $n!$, or in other words the permutation group $S_n$ has $n!$ elements

The number of tensor components of a tensor in $n$ dimensions $(d_1=1,d_2=2,\dots,d_n=n)$ is similarly $n!$ or in other words the set of the tensor components has $n!$ elements.

*update*

A tensor in $n$ dimensions as above has components $T^{i_1 i_2 \dots i_n}$, where each index $i_k$ ranges over $1 \dots k$ so total number of components is $1 \times 2 \times \dots \times n=n!$

In other words, it is the tensor product of $n$ vector spaces, where the $k$-th vector space has dimension $k$.

How about finding a bijection ("isomorphism") between these two objects?

Between a specific tensor component in $n$ dimensions as above sense and a specific permutation of $n$ elements.

*update2*

We are talking about finite objects in a combinatorial way. The original purpose is to find better/faster ways to generate (rank/unrank) permutations for $n$ elements from tensors (to both of which i have algorithms but searching for alternative schemes)

For example ranking and unranking tensors (tensor components) is very fast (linear time), but ranking/unranking permutations (in lexicographic order) requires log-linear time (with some latest algorithms). Something better using the bijection between these entities?

Comment: Why does the number of tensor components equal $n!$? Perhaps you could elaborate, or provide a reference to the book you're reading. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @EricAuld, a tensor in $n$ dimensions as above has components $T^{i_1 i_2 \dots i_n}$, where each index $i_k$ ranges over $1 \dots k$ so total number of components is $1 \times 2 \times \dots n=n!$

Comment: It does? Why? I know tensors, but perhaps we are talking about different things or this is an area of ignorance for me. "A tensor in $n$ dimensions" seems ambiguous unless you provide some more information. In particular, are you referring to the vector space being $n$ dimensional, or to the $n$-fold tensor product of the vector space? Or both?

Comment: This is not analytic, but algebraic/combinatoric, one can assume each $k$-th vector space (used in the tensor product) to have dimension $k$. But this is not the problem

Comment: @EricAuld, tensor product of $n$ vector spaces, where the $k$-th vector space has dimension $k$

Comment: So you have shown that there are $n!$ of each of them. There are many bijections between the two sets. In looking for an "isomorphism", what additional structure do you want? $S_n$ is a group...are you thinking that the tensor components form a group somehow?

Comment: @EricAuld, yes updating question to add what this is about. it is about combinatorics, trying to gerenate permutations from tensor components (to which both i have algorithms but searching for sth better/faster)

Comment: @EricAuld, yeah, ok, rephrased to bijection, instead of "isomorphism"

Comment: Try constructing a bijection between each one and the set $\{1, 2, \dotsc, n!-1, n\}$ and putting them together. In other words, find a way to number each set one through $n!$ and just declare the bijection to be that same number goes to same number.

Comment: @EricAuld, yes i have that already, ranking the permutation is slower than ranking the tensor, that is why i try to avoid it and use a (faster if possible) bijection from tensor to permutation

Comment: Not to be difficult, but what do you mean by "faster"?

Comment: @EricAuld, its ok, you see ranking permutations in lexicographic order requires log-linear time $O(n \log n)$ while ranking tensors requires linear time $O(n)$ so if a suitable bijection is found between a tensor comp. and a permutation in linear time, then the whole perumtation ranking is also linear time (fastest)

Comment: OK, I would include this in your question so people know what you want. :)

Comment: @EricAuld, for your information this could also be a research question, since no such known algorithm exists at this time (to my knowledge), linear algorithms exist but in awkward orderings , not lexicographic

Comment: @MattSamuel, it is about bijectionwhich hopefuly requires only linear-time to be computed, surely not all of them are such, if any one is, it is of great merit, if none, then it is an answer, although does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the bijection, implied by the equality of sizes, is the [set of permutation inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) which is also of size $n!$.

There is a fast linear mapping (ie the identity mapping) between tensor components and permutation inversions.

However the mapping between an inversion and its associated permutation (in lexicographic order) is not linear according to latest algorithms (and not likely to be in the future)

Comment: Wait, so what is the bijection? Also what do you mean by "linear" in the last sentence?

Comment: @runway44, For example take a 3x2x1 tensor it has 6! components which when expanded as indices (eg, [0,0,0], [2,1,0], ..) correspond to the set of inversions of the prmutations of 6 items. This is the bijection. Linear is meant in the sense of computational complexity that is O(n)